# Should it be better if answering/commenting on Meta requires at least 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion, meta, privileges

People answering on Meta should have a good understanding of a Stack Exchange community, so should it be better if answering/commenting on Meta requires at least 50 (or more?) reputation on that Stack Exchange community?

Comment: I hardly ever see this really go wrong, except for new question askers on meta which you have ruled out here. Is there a meta in the network where low rep users comment and answer that don't have a good understanding *and* are not corrected with a comment, flags. votes or better answers from the other users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers by new users bump the question to the front page; because meta sites have much less traffic than main sites, many people will see the answer and be able to downvote or flag it if appropriate. That's probably also the reason there is no First Posts or Late Answers queue on Meta sites.

Commenting on a 'child' meta already requires 50 reputation or more (except on Meta Stack Exchange, where [5 reputation is required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)).

So while I agree with "People answering on Meta should have a good understanding of a Stack Exchange community", I don't think a reputation barrier will help solving problems which aren't really there in the first place. Also, I've seen quite a lot of instances where *high*-reputation users didn't seem to know how their community worked; I probably belonged to that group myself until I spent some significant time on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: A rep barrier will definitely not solve any problem. Rep level definitely doesn't indicate knowledge of SE. Case in point: my anonymous editing.

Comment: Well, there's certainly a positive correlation between rep level and SE knowledge ...

Comment: A nearly 30k-rep user [asked an off-topic question to force the creation of a tag, and acted rudely after people started downvoting and closing his question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275303/forcing-a-new-tag-by-writing-an-offtopic-question). A user without enough rep to make edits, let alone an account, made hundreds of rather awesome edits to posts on Meta. Obviously there isn't much of a correlation.

Comment: But those are the exceptions, not the rule.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/794486/total-score-of-meta-posts-average-per-reputation-bracket#graph) shows that from just above 100 reputation, users tend to have a higher total post score on Meta Stack Overflow when they have higher reputation. This is about as quantitative as I can make it.

Comment: (the peak at 1 reputation is caused by ex-developers and suspended users, as can be seen from [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/794488/top-meta-posts-by-1-reputation-users))